# Decreasing sequence of compact sets

Tags: real-analysis

Let $\{K_i\}_{i=1}^\infty$ be a decreasing sequence of nonempty compact sets in some topological space.  How can I show that  $\bigcap_{i=1}^∞K_i≠∅$?
Is there any counterexample for the corresponding result for closed sets?

Comment: Is the space metrizable and complete ? Does $diam(K_i)\underset{i\to \infty }{\longrightarrow }0$ ? Otherwise it's obvious !

Comment: A counterexample is $\Bbb{N}$ with the cofinite topology, $K_n = \{ n, n+1 , n+2 , \dots \}$. Another one is $\Bbb{R}$ with the indiscrete topology, $K_n = [n, +\infty)$.

Answer (score 1):

(I'll use *sequence compactness* here; for metric spaces this is equivalent to compactness)

Pick $x_n\in K_n$. As $x_n\in K_1$, there is a converging subsequence, so we may assume wlog. that the original sequence is already convergent, say $x_n\to x_\infty$.
For any $i$, we have $x_n\in K_i$ for almost all $n$, hence $x_\infty\in K_i$ for all $i$.

A counterexample for closed sets is $A_n=[n,\infty)$ in $\Bbb R$.

Answer (score 0):

We can also directly use the definition of compactness: For the sake of notation, let $K_1$ be the ambient topological space.

Let the intersection be $\emptyset$, then we have an open cover $K_1 = \bigcup_{i=2}^\infty K_i^c$. By definition we find a finite subcover, i.e. $K_1 = \bigcup_{i=1}^N K_i^c$ for some $N$. This means $K_N = \bigcap_{i=1}^N K_i = \emptyset$, contradiction!

Comment: This is correct, but requires $K_1$ to be Hausdorff.

Comment: Compact = Hausdorff + quasi compact. Furthermore the tag is "real analysis"....

Comment: I see. The usual misunderstanding coming from different definitions of compactness comes out.

Comment: This misunderstanding only happens, if you even care about it. If you do analysis, you will work with Hausdorff spaces anyway, so you can just call the "finite-cover-definition" compact. If you do algebraic geometry, you will almost never work with Hausdorff spaces, so you will call the "finite-cover-definition" quasi-compact and keep in mind that quasi-compact sets might be not closed. In our situation, we obviously deal with the first case, i.e. our compact sets will be closed.